# How to extend Fragment with YoutubeBaseActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I am trying to implement youtube video functionality inside my android app. My app uses a navigation bar, that works by having one activity and a fragment for each screen. One of those screens needs to have video playback through the youtube API. For the youtube api to work, the activity/fragment where the video is playing, needs to extend to YoutubeBaseActivity. However, fragments already extends to Fragment, and it is not possible to extend to more than one thing.

I have been trying to solve this problem for many hours now, and have found several posts here on stackOverflow. However, every single one was either too old (pre-androidx) or just doesnt work.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.myapp.yt.PlayerConfig;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.myapp.R;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/

public class StartFragment extends  Fragment {

YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
Button play;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;


public StartFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);

    play = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    youTubePlayerView = view.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("HgzGwKwLmgM");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(PlayerConfig.API_KEY, onInitializedListener);
        }
    });

    return view;

}

}
```

Do you have ani idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: To use YoutubePlayerView, we will need to extend th Activity with YoutubeBaseActivity which is not androidX compatible. so we can not use it in AndroidX projects

Comment: You will need to use Fragment (YoutubeFragment) or WebViewPlayer PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player:

Answer (score 0):

Fragments live in Activity. Just extend your activity from YouTubeBaseActivity.

Sample

```
BaseActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity

A Activity extends BaseActivity
 - AFooFragment 
 - ABarFragment
B Activity extends BaseActivity
 - BFooFragment
 - BBarFragment
```

Comment: I put code in main question, can u have a look how to solve this problem?